# Not sure why my python output is looping

Tags: python, loops

I wrote a little bit of code to read a number in a file. Append it to a variable, then increment the number so the next time it runs the number in the file will be number +1. It looks like its working except it seems to increment twice.. For example here is my code :

```
 11 def mcIPNumber():
 12         with open('mcIPlatest.txt', 'r+') as file:
 13                 NameNumber= file.read().replace('\n','')
 14                 NameNumber=int(NameNumber)
 15                 NewNumber= NameNumber+1
 16                 print "newnumber = %s" % NewNumber
 17                 file.seek(0)
 18                 file.write(str(NewNumber))
 19                 file.truncate()
 20         return NameNumber
 21
 22 def makeNameMCTag():
 23         NameNumber = mcIPNumber()
 24         NameTag = "varName" + str(NameNumber)
 25         print "Name Tag: %s" % NameTag
 26         mcGroup = "varTagmc"
 27         #IPNumber = 1
 28         mcIP = "172.16.0.%s" % NameNumber
 29         print ( "Multicast Tag: %s, %s" % (mcGroup,mcIP))
 30
 31 
 32 mcIPNumber()
 33 makeNameMCTag()
```

But here is my output.. notice that "NewNumber" gets printed out twice.. for some reason"

```
newnumber = 2
newnumber = 3
Name Tag: varName2
Multicast Tag: varTagmc, 172.16.0.2
```

So it correctly made my varName2 and my IP 172.16.0.2 (incremented my initial number in the file by 1) but this means the 2nd time I run it.. I get this:

```
newnumber = 4
newnumber = 5
Name Tag: varName
Multicast Tag: varTagmc, 172.16.0.4
```

My expected result is this:

```
newnumber = 3
Name Tag: varName3
Multicast Tag: varTagmc, 172.16.0.3
```

Any idea why its looping?

Thanks!

(by the way if you're curious I'm trying to write some code which will eventually write the tf file for my TerraForm lab)

Comment: Did you not notice that you had called `mcIPNumber()` twice in your code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because of this:

```
 def makeNameMCTag():
     NameNumber = mcIPNumber()
```

You are calling mcIPNumber from inside makeNameMCTag, so you don't excplicitly need to call that method in line 32.

Alternatively

```
def make_name_mc_tag(name_number):
    NameTag = "varName" + str(name_number)
    print "Name Tag: %s" % NameTag
    ...

make_name_mc_tag(mcIPNumber())
```

here you are passing the required data as a parameter.

Comment: Looks like thats it.. But them in stuck, if I comment out 23 then I get an error:

   NameError: global name 'NameNumber' is not defined`code`


But if I comment out like 32 then the rest of that function won't run

Comment: My suggestion was to remove 32

Comment: yeah if I remove like 32 then the rest of the function won't run.. It would work if instead of NameNumber= mcIPNumber().. if I can somehow pass NameNumber into the makeNameTag() function. Then I wouldnt have to call it. Not sure how to do that tho

Comment: That would be true if you removed *23* i am talking about _32_

Comment: I'm an idiot. Thanks that was it. I actually got it working by declaring a var as global then removing line 23 all together.. But im not sure if that was good practice.

Comment: Nopes, using globals isn't a good idea. You can consider passing it as a parameter.